# Mariadb: store databases in alternative location

Tags: mariadb

I'd like to store my MariaDB databases in a location other than the default (`/var/lib/mysql`). I've created a folder `/home/kst/mysql` for this. I then stopped mariadb and I've edited the `datadir` line in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` to read: `datadir = /home/kst/mysql`. When I attempt to restart mariadb it doesn't work.

`Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

systemctl status mariadb.service gives:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.21 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-10-20 12:20:53 BST; 18s >
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             
    Process: 6312 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var>
    Process: 6313 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_ST>
    Process: 6315 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && >
    Process: 6362 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER>
   Main PID: 6362 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 263ms

Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.21 database server...
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [Warning] Can't c>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: [93B blob data]
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-c>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.21 database se>
```

And journalctl -xe gives:

```
xxx@rasp-4:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d $ journalctl -xe
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 sudo[6309]:      kst : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/mysql/maria>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 sudo[6309]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for >
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.21 database server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2496.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [Warning] Can't c>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: [93B blob data]
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=>
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-c>
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-co>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.21 database se>
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2496 and the job result is failed.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 sudo[6309]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for >
Oct 20 12:25:37 raspi-4 sudo[6374]:      kst : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/mysql/maria>
Oct 20 12:25:37 raspi-4 sudo[6374]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for >
Oct 20 12:27:57 raspi-4 sudo[6374]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for >
lines 1534-1572/1572 (END)
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 sudo[6309]:      kst : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/mysql/mariadb.co>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 sudo[6309]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user >
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.21 database server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2496.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [Warning] Can't create>
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: [93B blob data]
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 mariadbd[6362]: 2023-10-20 12:20:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exite>
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 20 12:20:53 raspi-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.21 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
░░
...
```

I suspect that there is something else that needs to be edited but have no idea what. Searching tends tell me to edit /etc/.mysql/my.cnf but that file has no `datadir` line.

There are currently no databases created. Note that starting Mariadb (after recerting these changes) and trying `select @@datadir;` confirms `/var/lib/mysql` as the current data directory.

This is on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Bullseye.

Comment: The setting for data directory are defined in /etc/mysql/my.cnf (and other *.cnf) files. Change it there, move the files (and subdirectories) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: I wanted to have MariaDB (aka mysql) use a different default location for all databases. I am running this on a Raspberry Pi and constantly writing to the memory card wears it out so I wanted to keep software installs there but data elsewhere. I have a USB drive for this purpose that also happens to be much larger in size. I wanted to store my data in a new folder that will also hold some HTML files for a website.

So here's how I managed to get this working.

1. From the command line stop MariaDB:`sudo systemctl stop mysql`
2. Check it is down: `sudo systemctl status mysql`
3. Create the destination folder: `mkdir /media/new_folder/mysql`
4. Copy all the files to the new location: `sudo cp -a /var/lib/mysql/* /media/new_folder/mysql`
   Note: `-a` keeps file permissions etc
5. Edit the `my.cnf` file (`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`) to add:

```bash
[mysqld]
datadir=/media/new_folder/mysql
socket=/media/new_folder/mysql/mysql.sock
[client]
port=3306
socket=/media/new_folder/mysql/mysql.sock
```

6. Use `^O` to save the file and `^X` to exit.
7. Edit the `50-server.cnf` file (`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`) to change the `datadir` line to:

```bash
datadir                 = /media/new_folder/mysql
```

8. Use `^O` to save the file and `^X` to exit.
9. If you try to restart mysql now you'll most likely get an error message:

```bash
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is despite using `-a` when copying the file across. The reason for this I'll admit I don't really understand.

10. Anyway, you'll need to set some file permissions:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
sudo chown mysql:mysql /media/new_folder/mysql
```

11. Now you can restart MariaDB: `sudo systemctl restart mysql`
12. Check it is up and running: `sudo systemctl status mysql`
13. Log in to MariaDB using you admin user: `mysql -u your_admin_user -p`
14. Create a test database: `create database test_db;`
15. From MariaDB show where you databases are located: `select @@datadir;`

```
+-------------------------------+ 
| @@datadir                     |
+-------------------------------+ 
| /media/new_folder/mysql/      | 
+-------------------------------+
```

16. Exit mysql: `exit`
17. From the command line check if your database in indeed there with: `ls -l /media/new_folder/mysql`. You should see an line something like:

    ```bash
    drwx------ 2 mysql mysql      4096 Oct 24 14:53 test_db
    ```
18. If so, you're all done.

Part of the confusion I had before was that I was a) given instructions to look for `my.cnf` in another location and b) when I found it I noted it did not contain `datadir` line but did not think to add it (cf. just editing it). It seems that this in fact needed to added (see step 5).

This was all based on the instructions [here](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2018/06/how-to-move-mariadb-data-directory-to.html) (with a couple of minor changes).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much except it looks like you have pasted truncated logs.
Things after "[Warning] Can't create>" might help diagnose the issue.

However, why not try "leaving it where it is" but replace the directory with a symbolic link pointing where you want the data stored?